# How to delete data with foreign key?

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, laravel-8

I need some help to delete a movie from my database.

I know that since I have **pivot tables** I will get some troubles with **foreign key**(my delete controller gives this error), but I don't know how to solve it.

The error i'm getting is the following:
*SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sakila`.`film_category`, CONSTRAINT `fk_film_category_film` FOREIGN KEY (`film_id`) REFERENCES `film` (`film_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: delete from `film` where `film_id` = 999)*

[My database tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPTaH.png)

Here are my ***models***:

> model Film:

```
class film extends Model{
    protected $table = "film";  
    protected $primaryKey = 'film_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $sql=['film_id', 'title', 'length'];

    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(category::class,'film_category', 'film_id', 'category_id');
    }        
    public function actor(){
              return $this->belongsToMany(actor::class,'film_actor', 'film_id', 'actor_id');
    }    
}
```

> model Category:

```
class category extends Model{
    protected $table = "category";
    protected $primaryKey = 'category_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $sql=['category_id','name'];

    public function film(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(film::class,'film_category', 'category_id', 'film_id');
    }
}
```

> model Actor:

```
class actor extends Model{
    protected $primaryKey = 'actor_id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    use HasFactory;
    protected $sql=['actor_id', 'first_name', 'last_name'];

    public function film(){
          return $this->belongsToMany(film::class,'film_actor', 'actor_id', 'film_id');
      }
}
```

Now I need some help to make my controller function to delete records.

```
 public function remove($film_id){
        $film=film::findOrFail($film_id);
        $film->delete();
        
        return redirect('/film/view');
```

Thanks

Comment: I cannot find the error message

Comment: @TirdadAbbasi the error is the following: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`sakila`.`film_category`, CONSTRAINT `fk_film_category_film` FOREIGN KEY (`film_id`) REFERENCES `film` (`film_id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE) (SQL: delete from `film` where `film_id` = 999)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To delete a movie, you must first delete the records from the `Film_category` and `Film_actor` table before you can delete your record from the `Film` table.

Instead do something like :

(assuming you have created your models from the `Film_category` and `Film_actor` tables)

```
public function remove($film_id){

    $film_category = FilmCategory::where('film_id', $film_id)->delete();
    $film_actor = FilmActor::where('film_id', $film_id)->delete();
    
    $film = film::findOrFail($film_id);
    $film->delete();
            
    return redirect('/film/view');
  
}
```

Comment: Your welcome ! PS. don't forget to accept this answer :)